# How to convert xml bean to spring java bean

Tags: java, spring

I want to convert this xml into new Spring Java bean

```
<bean id="velocityEngine"class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean">
<property name="velocityProperties">
    <map>
       <entry key="resource.loader" value="ds"/>
       <!--<entry key="ds.resource.loader.class" value="org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.DataSourceResourceLoader"/>--><!--should be left out-->
       <entry key="ds.resource.loader.resource.table" value="templates" />
       <entry key="ds.resource.loader.resource.keycolumn" value="tid" />
       <entry key="ds.resource.loader.resource.templatecolumn" value="template" />
       <entry key="ds.resource.loader.resource.timestampcolumn" value="updated" />
       <entry key="ds.resource.loader.instance" value-ref="dataSourceLoader" />  
       <entry key="ds.resource.loader.cache" value="true" />  
    </map>
</property>
```

and can anybody tell clearly how this conversion carrying out, and how this works

Java class starts as

@bean

Comment: As a note, this is the sort of thing that's much prettier with Groovy.

Comment: Some good docs: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_java_based_configuration.htm

Answer (score 0):

Should be added to your @Configuration marked class something like this

```
@Bean
public VelocityEngineFactoryBean velocityEngine() {
    VelocityEngineFactoryBean b = new VelocityEngineFactoryBean ();
    b.setVelocityProperties(the map with all your key values);
    return b;
}
```

If some of the values are another beans e.g. dataSourceLoader you can just @Autowire them to the same class and use the properties

Comment: Unless the dependencies are used multiple times in the class, it's generally better to wire them as method parameters.

Comment: VelocityEngineFactory appears as deprecation

Answer (score 0):

Your java class should be annotated with @Configuration annotation and the method should be annotated with @Bean.  please refer below

```
@Configuration
class AppConfiguration{

    @Bean
    public VelocityEngine velocityEngine() throws VelocityException, IOException{
        VelocityEngineFactoryBean factory = new VelocityEngineFactoryBean();
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("resource.loader", "ds");
        props.put("class.resource.loader.class","org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.DataSourceResourceLoader");
        props.put("class.resource.loader.resource.table","templates");
        props.put("ds.resource.loader.resource.keycolumn","tid");
        props.put("ds.resource.loader.resource.templatecolumn","template");
        props.put("ds.resource.loader.resource.timestampcolumn","updated");
        props.put("ds.resource.loader.instance","dataSourceLoader");
        props.put("ds.resource.loader.cache",true);
        factory.setVelocityProperties(props);

        return factory.createVelocityEngine();
    }
}
```

for more information about Java based configuration, you can refer https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.8.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java-basic-concepts